# I am working on flightradar 24 examples and get json decode error

Tags: javascript, python

```
import flightradar24
airline = 'THY'  # Turkish Airlines
fr = flightradar24.Api()
flights = fr.get_flights(airline)
```

> Error /// json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column
> 1 (char 0) I appricitae your help.  thanks

Error details:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    fr = flightradar24.Api()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flightradar24/core.py", line 28, in __init__
    response = api_request(self.balanceJsonUrl, self.proxies)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flightradar24/helpers.py", line 17, in api_request
    return r.json()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0
```

Comment: I expect you're getting a non-JSON error response from the web API that your API is calling. Can you trace out the exact HTTP response somehow? i.e. what exactly is it trying to decode?

Comment: It may be that the API class you have is out of date and is trying to use an old URL that doesn't exist anymore. It's probably also asking flightradar directly for help, particularly if one of their examples is broken. Can you link to the documentation you're following please?

Comment: It looks like an internal API problem. `flightradar24` is using `requests` and make an HTTP for your line of code: `flightradar24.Api()`. The `requests` lib try to covert the response to JSON and fail.

Comment: The Python call stack doesn't tell us much, except maybe where you would have access to the response: if there's no built-in way to trace out the response, you could look at the lines in flightradar24/core.py and flightradar/helpers.py from the call stack and add some code to pprint out the response there.

Comment: I think there is problem with your internet connection. Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/mkorkmaz/flightradar24/blob/b8c14aa17c970672bf4f286aa6630192f450c3cd/flightradar24/core.py#L9) the url `self.balanceJsonUrl` is `https://www.flightradar24.com/balance.json` and it indeed returns JSON, e.g. `{"data-live.flightradar24.com":1000}`

Comment: find `helpers.py` and print  `r.status_code` and `r.text` so that you see what you get. Also, are you behind proxy? You may need to pass `proxies` when instantiate `Api()`